# Not able to access new method in derived class

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have written the following piece of code for crawling web pages and then storing them in the `Solr` index.

```
crawledLinks = []
solr = pysolr.Solr('some url', timeout=10)

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "tutsplus"
    start_urls = ["some url"]
    allowed_domains = ["some domain"]

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 100,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 100,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 100,
        'LOG_ENABLED': True,
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        current_url = response.url

        asyncio.ensure_future(add_to_index(response.body, current_url))

        for link in links:
        # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
            internal_link = urljoin(current_url, link)
            result = urlparse(internal_link)

            if result.scheme and result.netloc and result.path and not internal_link in crawledLinks:
                crawledLinks.append(internal_link)
                yield Request(internal_link, self.parse)

        item = TutsplusItem()
        item["url"] = current_url

        yield item

    async def add_to_index(body, current_url):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(body)
        texts = soup.find_all(text=True)

        visible_texts = []

        for text in texts:
            if text.parent.name not in ['style', 'script', 'meta', '[document]'] and not isinstance(text, Comment):
            visible_texts.append(text)

            fetched_text = u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)
            words = nltk.word_tokenize(fetched_text)
            stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
            stopwordsfree_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop]

            detokenizer = MosesDetokenizer()
            doc = detokenizer.detokenize(stopwordsfree_words, return_str=True)
            doc = doc.encode('utf-8')

            url = "some url"

            try:
                res = requests.post(url, data=doc)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            if not doc:
                doc = soup.title.string

            if res.status_code == 200:
                words = json.loads(res.text) 
                doc = detokenizer.detokenize(words, return_str=True)
                solr.add([{"doc": doc, "url": str(current_url)}])
```

I want to call the function `add_to_index()` in a "fire and forget" manner. But the problem I'm facing is I'm getting the error

> undefined name 'add_to_index'

in the parse method. So function is not being recognized. I'm new to python. Could you help me with this issue?

Thanks,

Nilesh.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `add_to_index` like so: `self.add_to_index(response.body, current_url)`

Comment: I tried just now. The IDE is not showing the error now. Thanks. Let me try and run it.

Comment: Probably also will need `self` as the first arg in the `add_to_index` function.

Comment: Yeah, had to add that. It's running now. Thanks :)